# refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ' ? ts(2749)

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I was developing a minesweeper game in typescript. But while defining a type named `Cell`, I encountered an error.

Code:

**Not Working**

```js
const bomb = "&#128163;";
const flag = "&#128681;";

export type Cell = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | bomb | flag;

export type Board = Array<Array<Cell>>;
```

While defining `type Cell` the error raises:

`'bomb' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof bomb'?ts(2749)`

while doing it in another way without any variable or constant works:

**Fine**

```js
export type Cell = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | "&#128163;" | "&#128681;";
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bomb` and `flag` and not types.

The `typeof` operator will give you access to the type of a value.

```
const bomb = "&#128163;";
const flag = "&#128681;";

export type Cell = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | typeof bomb | typeof flag;
```